# Floating layout similar to HTML/CSS

Tags: apache-flex, layout, adobe, overflow, css-float

In HTML/CSS, if you float items, DIV's that exceed the width of the container are moved down 1 line.

I would like to achieve this in FLEX. I have 3 components with variable width. I would like for the 3rd component to be moved down when it doesnt fit the container any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a FlowLayout.  Here's an example for Flex 4:
http://evtimmy.com/2009/06/flowlayout-a-spark-custom-layout-example/

If you are looking for something that works pre-Flex 4 (Spark), you can search for "flex flow layout" or "flex flowbox" and find several examples.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Weird though that this is not available out-of-the box. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to upvote or mark as answered. :)